# upload image from expo RN project to google cloud functions

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, expo

https://medium.com/@wcandillon/uploading-images-to-firebase-with-expo-a913c9f8e98d

I have been following this great post on how to use expo to upload an image to google cloud functions with google storage but I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: handler is not a function
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:26:41)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:671:7
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:655:9
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

Any help is appreciated. I don't have experience developing express apps but I might need to if I don't find an answer soon.

Comment: Please show your code the reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response. I found the issue. I was not using module.exports on code for it to be exported to the index file where all my google cloud functions are registered that is the code below

```
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(api);
```

thanks for the response either way.